# Заполнение Jtable из постоянно обновляющейся таблицы БД

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Задача состоит в следующем:
Есть функция которая по API берет данные(в виде Collection) и после проверки определенных условий записывает данные в БД(MySQL). 
Нужно эти данные по мере поступления либо сразу заполнять в  Jtable либо записывать их из БД.
Но как реализовать это так, чтобы таблица заполнялась постепенно по мере поступления записей? Либо чтобы таблица обновлялась с определенным интервалом времени?

Comment: А сколько данных в таблице и сколько будет? Это точно хорошая мысль наполнять всей информацией из таблицы? Почему просто не сделать перезагрузку таблицы когда нужно?

Comment: В БД записываются все данные по определенному фильтру и там их очень много(более 1000). А в  Jtable нужно выводить "особые" записи (другой фильтр) - записей там будет не много не более 10 позиций. И как только найдется необходимая запись, нужно либо что-бы она появилась в JTable либо вообще в отдельном всплывающем окне, для немедленной обработки. Поэтому сидеть сутками и перезагружать таблицу вручную - не целесообразно. Есть метод с определенным интервалом обновлять таблицу автоматически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готового метода нет.
Вам необходимо при запуске приложения в отдельном потоке запускать задачу, которая будет через заданный Вами интервал проверять наличие необходимых данных, показывать всплывающее сообщение и обновлять таблицу.
Можете воспользоваться планировщиком: Timer и TimerTask.